# React / Redux / Meteor: method that dispatches an action in the callback, is called twice

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, meteor, redux, redux-thunk

I have a React / Redux / Meteor app in which I dispatch an action, that calls a method to get a value from the server, and the method has a callback in which I dispatch an action to save the returned value in the Redux store.

I'm also using Redux thunk.

Although my original action is only dispatched once, it runs twice. It seems that dispatching an action from inside a method callback, is causing the original action to be dispatched again.

In my React component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    ....
    render() {
    ...
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return { value: state.myPartialState.value }
}

const Tracker = withTracker(({dispatch}) => {
const state = store.getState();
const isLoading = getIsLoading(state);
...

const handle = Meteor.subscribe('myData'), {
onReady: () => {
    'onReady': () => {
        secondaryPatternSubscriptions(patterns);
    },
});

if (isLoading && handle.ready()) {
    console.log('about to dispatch original action');
    dispatch(getValue());
    dispatch(setIsLoading(false));
} else if (!isLoading && !handle.ready()) {
    dispatch(setIsLoading(true));
}

return { ... }
)(MyComponent);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Tracker);
```

In my actions file:

```
export const SET_VALUE = 'SET_VALUE';

export function setValue(value) {
    return {
        'type': 'SET_VALUE',
        'payload': value,
    };
}

export const getValue = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log('about to call');
    Meteor.call('getValue', (error, result) => {
        console.log('about to dispatch second action');
        dispatch(setValue(result)); // this causes the action to be dispatched again
    });

    // dispatch(setValue(10)); // this only runs once
};

const initialState = {
    value: 0,
}

export default function myPartialState(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VALUE: {
            return updeep({ 'value': action.payload }, state);
        }
    }
}
```

On the server, the method is like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
'getValue': function () {
...
return value;
},
})
```

I can see from the console logs that getValue is only dispatched once, but runs twice. I have checked this again and again, and I'm pretty near 100% sure that getValue is not dispatched twice.

I think it's something to do with calling an action from inside the method callback; if I comment out dispatch(setValue(result)); and replace it with a dispatch outside the method call, then getValue only runs once.

If I dispatch a different action instead of setValue, or change the setValue action so that it doesn't alter the 'value' property in the store, then again getValue only runs once. But I can't see why changing 'value' would cause the action to be run twice, when it is only dispatched once...

I've searched online and haven't found anything about this issue.

Can anybody think why my action is running twice, and a way to have it run only once? Thanks!

Comment: My best guess is, `getValue()` is dispatched twice on the component that's using it. Please post a more detailed snippet, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the obvious thing and I've checked for it again and again in every way I can think of. I'm really pretty sure getValue() is not dispatched twice. I've added more code to the question and noted that if I change the second action to one that isn't mapped to the component, then the behaviour changes.

Comment: Can you try to comment out `dispatch(setValue(result));` and just leave the `console.log` there, then try to dispatch the action and see if it logs twice

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and it logs once only. It also logs once only if I dispatch a different action, or if I change this action so that it does not change 'value' in the store. And it runs once only if I move dispatch(setValue(10)) to below the method call.

Comment: Where is the `loaded` state coming from?

Comment: Ah, I simplified that bit of code for the question. If I remove the loaded check altogether, the action is dispatched many times, and almost always the action runs once per time it is dispatched. But on ONE occasion, it is consistently shown from the logging to run twice, when it is called once!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206380/discussion-between-karlmarxlopez-and-little-brain).